# how to fix this if else statement?c prog

Tags: c

What should I do to fix this?

```
Piece player1,player2;


printf("\nChess\n");

printf("\nInput Player 1 name:");
scanf("%s",&player1.plaVar.name);

printf("\nPlayer 1 color:(black or white):");
scanf("%s",&player1.plaVar.color);
fflush(stdin);

if(player1.plaVar.color=="b","l","a","c","k")
{
    printf("\nPlayer 2  is white\n");
    fflush(stdin);
}
else if(player1.plaVar.color=="w","h","i","t","e")
{
    printf("\nPlayer 2 color is black\n");
    fflush(stdin);
}

printf("\nInput Player 2 name:");
scanf("%s",&player2.plaVar.name);
```

The result of this code:
player1 name: neee

player1 color(black or white):white

player 2 color:white
//it should be black

Comment: `player1.plaVar.color=="w","h","i","t","e"`, don't guess the syntax (C has a habit of compiling funny syntax) read a good book. K & R is my favourite.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you fix this code by learning C, which makes this question too broad.

Comment: SInce you `scanf` as a string into the `color` fields, I'm assuming that they're strings. The `==` operator can't be used for string comparison in C. What you do here is compare the pointer to the string `player1.plaVar.color` to the pointers to strings `"k"` and `"e"`. This is definitely not what you want to do. I'd recommend looking up the `strcmp` function.

Comment: What do you intend to express by "b","l","a","c","k"? C strings would look like "black", and they are not compared using == but using strcmp() and related functions. Please take some kind of C programming course, asking questions about absolute basics on SO will not make you popular :-)

Answer (score -1):

All,

Actually I was very surprised the see the 'if' statement in the source above is correct - checked in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf . Such construct is compilable (checked on GCC 7.3). I learn something new every day...

But going back to the origin of issue:

I am having trouble to understand `scanf("%s",&player1.plaVar.name);` which tells me you want to input a string and then `if(player1.plaVar.color=="b","l","a","c","k")` is a variable of unknown type (you did not include definition of that) compared to one of possible values of strings. I guess you try to compare strings, so in that case the best way is to use `strcmp()` function as @Thomas Jager suggested.

Also I do not think this way of coding `if` comparison is a proper one from readability point of view. Please look for information on how to write clean and maintainable code.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct player
{
    char name[100];
    char color[6];
}Player;

typedef struct piece
{
    Player plaVar;
}Piece;

int main()
{
    Piece player1,player2;


    printf("\nChess\n");

    printf("\nInput Player 1 name:");
    scanf("%s",&player1.plaVar.name);

    printf("\nPlayer 1 color:(black or white):");
    scanf("%s",&player1.plaVar.color);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(!strcmp(player1.plaVar.color, "black"))
    {
        printf("\nPlayer 2  is black\n");
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(player1.plaVar.color, "white"))
    {
        printf("\nPlayer 2 color is black\n");
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    printf("\nInput Player 2 name:");
    scanf("%s",&player2.plaVar.name);   
    return 0;
}
```